# Sum of n terms.. 122333=14

Tags: java, count, sum

im need to calculate the sum of n terms i wrote this code but it print me all the nums but no the sum

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){ 
        System.out.print(i);
    }  
}
```

And this is what it print

122333444455555

Thanks for your help

Comment: sum is usually when you add numbers together `int sum = 1 + 2;`  I do not see anything like this in your code.

Comment: Indeed summing usually accumulates, e.g. `sum = sum + i`

Answer (score 3):

If by 'sum of N terms' you mean,

N=4

Sum= 1+2+2+ 3+3+3+4+4+4+4....N*N

Then it's safe to say that it's Sum(i*i) where 0<i<=N,
this solution will give you answer:

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += i * i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Your counter goes from *`0`* to *`n - 1`*, while it should go from *`1`* to *`N`*. Change your `for` loop to `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

One good approach here is make use of the modulus:

```java
int input = 122333;
int sum = 0;

while (input > 0) {
    sum += input % 10;
    input /= 10;
}

System.out.println("Sum of all terms is: " + sum);  // 14
```

The `input % 10` term will return the final rightmost digit in the input.  We added this to the running total, and then divide the input by 10 to advance the next digit.

Comment: Are you sure that's what they are trying to do? My interpretation is that they are summing 1, 2,2, 3,3,3, ... n,....n.

Comment: @tgdavies ... what the OP is currently doing does not agree with the problem statement, which, oddly enough, appears in the title of the question only: `Sum of n terms.. 122333=14`

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){

  for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){    
    res=res+i;

    System.out.print(i);
                                
        }                           
}
                        
System.out.println(" La sumatoria es "+res);
```